# Problem calling custom delegate method on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

In my iPhone application...

Could not call the delegate method ...

Here is my code

I have created a simple delegate in one class...

```
@protocol imagecelldelegate

-(BOOL) isIntersects:(CGRect)lastTouch;

@end

@interface ImageDemoGridViewCell : AQGridViewCell
{
    id<imagecelldelegate> delegate; 
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id delegate;

@end
```

Now I have set the delegate in this class's implementation and called the delegate method.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setDelegate:self.superview];

    [delegate isIntersects:originalSelf];
     //Getting error at this point...   

}
```

After that I have implemented the method in the class which I have set the delegate..

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<imagecelldelegate>
{
```

And implemented the method in this class....

```
-(BOOL) isIntersects:(CGRect)lastTouch
{

    NSLog(@"Delegate Yippee");

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? or "Delegate Yippee" is not logged?

Comment: When I am calling the method at that line getting the error..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self setDelegate:self.superview];
```

This is the problem.

You should set the `ViewController` as the reference for the delegate.

For example, after you have allocated the `ImageDemoGridViewCell` in `ViewController`, set the delegate as follows.

```
ImageDemoGridViewCell *cell = [[ImageDemoGridViewCell alloc] initWith..];
cell.delegate = self;
```

Then add the cell as subview to the `ViewController`s view.